# Read string format and fetch required irregular data

Tags: java, string, arraylist, collections, split

I have a string format like this which is output of

```
readAllBytes(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(data))
```

from a file

```
a+2  b+3 c+33 d+88 ......
```

My scenario is I want to get the data after `c+" "`. The position of `c` is not constant but `c` occurs only once. It may occur anywhere. My required value will always be after `c+` only. The required size of value 33.....is also not constant. Can someone help me with the optimal code please? I think collections need to be used here.

Comment: Could you specify an example in following format: inputText: __, expectedResult:  ___ ?

Comment: My input is a+2 b+3 c+33 d+88 and my required output is based onc that is  33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex which will let you capture the data you want,

```
c\+(\d+)
```

Explanation:

c+ matches a literal c character immediately followed by a + char
(\d+) captures the next digit(s) which you are interested in capturing.

Demo, https://regex101.com/r/jfYUPG/1

Here is a java code for demonstrating same,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "a+2 b+3 c+33 d+88 ";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("c\\+(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Data: " + m.group(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Input data doesn't match the regex");
    }
}
```

This gives following output,

```
Data: 33
```

Comment: String s = "sample=true properties=myproperties";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("properties\\=(\\d+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Data: " + m.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input data doesn't match the regex");
        }.....I tried this scenario but its giving wrong input..

Comment: Do you want to capture data appearing next to properties=? Then you need to write it like this properties=(\\w+) Also you don't need to escape = character. \\d is only for capturing digits, where as \\w is equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: yeah thanx for that I got it.But my required data is in a.b.c format.From the code you provided I got "a" as input .I need a.b.c as input

Comment: ok if you have dot in the text you want to capture, then use this character set [a-zA-Z.] If your text contains numbers then include numbers into the set with 0-9

Comment: Am not sure what I want to capture because it is given by end user.But it definetly contains (.) and may or maynot contains numerics.I should handle whatever the user gives it may be numrics or digit or dot(.).Please share me the  character set to handle......This might be the data to handle 23abv.#jgd.xyz. or abc23.cdj12.jk .It will definetly start with alphabets or numberics but not any spcial characters

Comment: ok if it is given by end user and it can contain any character then you may use this. Pattern.compile("properties=([^\s]+)");

Comment: Pattern.compile("properties=([^\s]+)") this is showing as illegal escape character

Comment: You need to escape slash and make it Pattern.compile("properties=([^\\s]+)")

Comment: Thanq sooooo much...it means a lot.AM very much new to this stuff thaq for the help and for the prompt replies.

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Comment: This code is working super fine but I want take an input and search for the data after that input .it is popping the first line of the data..(exmple).String filecontent = "firsline=firstlinedata "+ "secondline=secondlinedata "+ "thirdline=thirdlinedata"; String p2 = "secondline"; Pattern p = Pattern.compile(p2="([^\\s]+)"); Matcher m = p.matcher(filecontent);  if (m.find(1)) {  System.out.println("Data: " + m.group(1));...The obtained output is firstlinedata....but I want output to be secondlinedata.I think this is because of space in 1 line.How to assign to a string and fetch

Comment: @iamsj: I saw your code and there looks a little mistake where you are trying to construct the Pattern. replace your Pattern p = ... with this line, Pattern p = Pattern.compile(p2 + "=" + "([^\\s]+)"); and you should get what you expect. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 1):

This code is extracting the value right after `c+` up to the next space, or to the end of the string if there is no space:

```
String str = "a+2  b+3 c+33 d+88 ";
String find = "c+";

int index = str.indexOf(" ", str.indexOf(find) + 2);
if (index == -1)
    index = str.length();
String result = str.substring(str.indexOf(find) + 2, index);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
33
```

or in a method:

```
public static String getValue(String str, String find) {
    int index = str.indexOf(find) + 2; 
    int indexSpace = str.indexOf(" ", index);
    if (indexSpace == -1)
        indexSpace = str.length();
    return str.substring(index, indexSpace);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "a+2  b+3 c+33 d+88 ";
    String find = "c+";

    System.out.println(getValue(str, find));
}
```